# PYTHON - input decimal to fraction

Tags: python-3.x

When working on **python**, I was able to convert a fraction to a decimal where the user would input a numerator, then a denominator and then the `n/d = the result` (fairly simple).  But i can't work out how to convert a decimal into a fraction.  I want the user to input any decimal ( ie `0.5`) and then find the simplest form of `x (1/2)`. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `fractions` module.

```
from fractions import Fraction

f1 = Fraction(14, 8)
print(f)           # Output: 7/4
print(float(f))    # Output: 1.75

f1 = Fraction(1.75)
print(f)           # Output: 7/4
print(float(f))    # Output: 1.75
```

It accepts both pairs of numerator/denominator as well as float decimal numbers to construct a Fraction object.

Comment: Instead of writing "Thank you" as comment, please accept this answer by clicking the grey tick button on the left of it. You can also learn more about how this site works by spending two minutes on taking the [tour].